# visual studio setup deferred custom action

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, custom-action

Hi I am using visual studio i need to move some files around installing setup project msi after files are installed at the very end of installing. I create custom action vbs action and need administrative, I found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/12/13/some-useful-things-i-have-learned-about-windows-installer-and-uac.aspx and need to be deferred action but i cant find anywhere how to make a deferred action. His script add noimpoersonate at postbuild but only to deferred action.

How can i make a deferred vbs custom action so i can add noimpersonate so it can run administrative and move privileged files? Custom actiosn has install commit rollback uninstall, there isnt deferred or in properties to click deferred.

not wix it is visual studio setup msi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio custom actions are deferred by default so you should be ok, if deferred behavior is all you need. They are also no-impersonate by default, which means that they run with the system account and do not impersonate the calling user. You add a VBScript custom action by just adding the .VBS file in the Custom action view in the IDE.

"Moving files around" on files installed with Windows Installer is often a big issue. You cannot install a bunch of files to one location and then move them to some other location, deleting the original installed files, because Windows Installer will eventually notice and attempt to repair the now broken install, asking for the original install source. If you need them at some location then why not just install them in the first place?

Comment: Sorry i cant vote you. I cant bundle the files in the installer because they come from somewhere else, they are optional files if found on machine, they are not files that get installed they are other files. I made a vbscript and added custom action, it work fine when destination if folder with everyone write, but msi fails with script error when destination folder is in program files where i want to go. So i think it is not running administrative, thanks.

Comment: You should edit the question maybe because you're not really "

Comment: You should edit the question maybe because you're not really "moving files around" you have some files that you want to install by copying (from where?) to the ProgramFiles folder (or do you really mean to where the user installed the files with the Browse dialog?) Anyway, it's true that VS custom actions are already deferred+no-impersonate, so your issue is the script isn't working, it might help if you posted it. Your CA runs with the system account, security issues more likely to be that it is trying to go to the network where the system account has no access, for example.